# Why addEventListener function couldn't get global variable?

Tags: javascript, xml, html, popcornjs

I created a event listener function that call popcorn.js to display subtitle. I also create functions outside of event listener that are not relate to popcorn.js and declare global variable array. I want to print array result(c.innerHTML = subtitleArray[0][2];) in event listener but it show empty string even though it already stored in array. Please help!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 included Javascript....</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Test" charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <script src="popcorn.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                var subtitleArray = new Array(); //stored all values from XML caption file
                var firstLine;
                var c = document.getElementById('container');

                function loadXMLDoc(dname)
                {
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    {
                    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
                    xhttp.send();

                    return xhttp.responseXML;
                }

                function getCaption()
                {

                    var tempArray = new Array();


                    captionsDoc = loadXMLDoc("captions.xml");
                    x=captionsDoc.getElementsByTagName('text');

                    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
                    {
                        var tempArray = new Array();
                        tempArray[0] = x[i].getAttribute('start'); // get start time
                        tempArray[1] = x[i].getAttribute('dur'); // get duration time
                        tempArray[2] = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue; // get text

                        subtitleArray[i] = tempArray; //put all 3 values in array


                    }           

                    //c.innerHTML = subtitleArray[0][2];
                    firstLine = subtitleArray[0][2];

                } 

                document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

                    var popcorn = Popcorn("#video");
                    c.innerHTML = subtitleArray[0][2];

                    popcorn.subtitle({
                        start: 0,
                        end: 3,
                        text: "Hello World", // "Hello World" replace to subtitleArray[0][2]
                        target: "text"
                    }).subtitle({
                        start: 3,
                        end: 6,
                        text: "This is second line",
                        target: "text"
                    });

                    popcorn.play();
                }, false);

            window.onload = getCaption;

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls="true" preload="none">
                <source src="caption.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                <source src="caption.webm" type="video/webm" />
                <source src="caption.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
            </video> 
        </div>
        <div id="text" style="width:980px;height:50px;"></div>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous, so when you try to use the array, it's still empty.

Comment: Your `c` variable is inside the `getCaption` scope, not a global variable.

Comment: Put an alert in each function to see what order they're called in.

Comment: another problem is `DOMContentLoaded` fires before `window.onload` http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Zxcvj/

Comment: @adeneo, You are incorrect. Do you see the false? That makes this synchronous.

Comment: @neustroev.ai - Thank for catch my mistake and I edit it by move to global because I type it in wrong place but the result is the same which doesn't display anything

Comment: @epascarello - you're right, did'nt notice it. That's even worse IMO !

Comment: so how can I call getCaption function first before eventListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is you are running two different things that depend on each other at different times and you have scope issues with your global variables.

DOMContentLoaded runs before the onload event, so you are making the Ajax call after you are trying to use the returned value before the request is made.

Combine them so they both run at the same time.

Comment: how can I combine them both to run same time?

Comment: take the code from the one function and put it into the other in the correct order?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
var subtitleArray = new Array(); // stored all values from XML caption file
var firstLine;

function loadXMLDoc(dname, callback) {
    var xhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);
    xhttp.send();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            callback(xhttp.responseXML);
        }
    }
}

function getCaption() {

    var tempArray = new Array();
    var c = document.getElementById('container');

    loadXMLDoc("captions.xml", function(captionsDoc) {
                var x = captionsDoc.getElementsByTagName('text');
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    var tempArray = new Array();
                    tempArray[0] = x[i].getAttribute('start');
                    tempArray[1] = x[i].getAttribute('dur');
                    tempArray[2] = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    subtitleArray[i] = tempArray;

                }

                firstLine = subtitleArray[0][2];
                c.innerHTML = firstLine;
            });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var popcorn = Popcorn("#video");
            popcorn.subtitle({
                        start : 0,
                        end : 3,
                        text : "Hello World", // "Hello World" replace to
                        // subtitleArray[0][2]
                        target : "text"
                    }).subtitle({
                        start : 3,
                        end : 6,
                        text : "This is second line",
                        target : "text"
                    });

            popcorn.play();
        }, false);

window.onload = getCaption;
```